# Filtering Wordpress Contents based on URL

Tags: categories, domain

This is just a theoretical question for now.

Given a website that has items of content that are tagged into categories, for example "Coding" "Writing" "Gaming", it is possible to configure the site in some way that the categories are only available dependant on the incoming URL from which they are viewed?

For example, if everything is available on www.mysite.net, the coding posts are available at coding.mysite.net (with the other categories still available for view), and the coding posts available without any sign of the other categories on a seperate domain www.mycodingsite.com and using a different theme from the main site?

In this way I could "split out" a section of my site by category, and have it appear as a standalone website?

Comment: maybe this can do the trick for you, ?
wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Use the "Subdomains" plugin and you can do exactly what are you looking for :)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subdomains/

Cheers
Hasin

Answer (score 2):

Yes, i think you can work with 3 different ways.

1. use multisite and each blog in the network is an subdomain and his categories. Its great for maintenance and an default and also great for capabilities, no problems.
2. Use an custom pluign on filter `pre_get_posts()` and list in dependence on the url the categories for this url, only this. Filter the categories from other domain. Possible, but you must develop.
3. Use an plugin for different domain in a default install, single install, not multisite; maybe [123 Multihost](http://putzlowitsch.de/123-multihost/) (only german description, use g-translate) I think is a fast way, but not fine for maintenance in feature; to dependence to the plugin.